# How can I crop images only using HTML for my newsletter send?

Tags: html, email, rss, instagram, html-email

**Quick Introduction**
I am using Klaviyo for email and an RSS feed for Instagram data to include an Instagram feed block at the end of my emails. Ideally, the images coming from Instagram would have an aspect ratio of 1:1, but my attempts at cropping the images are warping the images, not cropping the images. Unfortunately, I am poor at HTML and would appreciate any help.

**Body**
I am using Klaviyo for my email sends and want to set up an Instagram feed at the bottom of emails.

This code is successful in creating three images from my RSS feed next to each other and linking to the original post on Instagram. Klaviyo suggested using this code for this specific use case.

```
<div>{% for item in feeds.brinn_ig_feed.rss.channel.item|slice:":3" %}
    <table style="display: inline-block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 18px; width: 150px;"><a href="{{ item.link }}"> <img
                            style="margin: 1px" src="{{ item.description }}" width="150" height="150" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[vertical images in IG block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Vx8.png)

However, I want to crop the images to be square. I have very limited experience in HTML, so after some time experimenting, I got this code, however, the images aren't cropped, they are just being resized.

```
<div>{% for item in feeds.brinn_ig_feed.rss.channel.item|slice:":3" %}
    <table style="display: inline-block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 18px; width: 150px;"><a href="{{ item.link }}"> <img
                            style="margin:1px; overflow:hidden; aspect-ratio: 1/1" src="{{ item.description }}" /></a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[square images in IG block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhujd.png)

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Ideally, these three images would be cropped square without distorting the images.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you've got your two code sections mixed up? Also, you code is not normal HTML, it looks like [twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html) code.

Comment: Thanks! I guess Klaviyo is using twig code (first time I'm hearing this phrase tbh, so I appreciate the insight!). The `feeds.brinn_ig_feed.rss.channel.item` variable comes from the way Klaviyo connects to RSS feeds. And the sections with {{ }} reference the data from that data connection. And, I just rechecked those two code blocks and the first block is definitely the code that outputs three vertical images and the second block is definitely the code squashing the images to fit into a square.